# SimpleXML::addChild() can't add line break when output to a xml

Tags: php, simplexml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><items>
<item><title>title3</title><desc>This is some desc3</desc></item></items>
```

There is no line break between each node element when using asXML() to output?

How to make output the file well-structured by adding a line break after each XML elements opening and closing tag that contains child element nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
<item>
<title>title3</title>
<desc>This is some desc3</desc>
</item>
</items>
```

Comment: use DOMDocument it has option to format html/xml data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *SimpleXML* extension is limited to format the output, it's sister extension, [*DOMDocument*](http://php.net/DOMDocument) has support for output formatting. The XML string from your example and making use of `DOMDocument::$preserveWhiteSpace` and `DOMDocument::$formatOutput` to control the formatttings:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$doc->loadXML($string);

echo $doc->saveXML();
```

This will output a nicely indented XML with the linebreaks where you have asked for them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
  <item>
    <title>title3</title>
    <desc>This is some desc3</desc>
  </item>
  <empty/>
</items>
```

If you further need to manipulate the indent, you can make use of regular expressions which has been outlined in a related question and answer: ***[Converting indentation with preg_replace (no callback)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8616594/367456)***.

If you don't want to use that method you could also switch from SimpleXML to something else and then to XMLWriter which provides a method to set the indentation ([XMLWriter::setIndent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-set-indent.php)) of printed XML. You would need to find an interim representation of your XML model to write it with `XMLWriter` however which does not look that trivial.